# sequential binary TCL

Tags: binary, tcl

Please suggest improvements to my program. This program gives a 4 bit binary incremental o/p
I am looking for optimizing this where there is unnecessary code.

Please suggest improvements to my program. This program gives a 4 bit binary incremental o/p
I am looking for optimizing this where there is unnecessary code.
Please suggest improvements to my program. This program gives a 4 bit binary incremental o/p
I am looking for optimizing this where there is unnecessary code.

```
        #!/bin/sh
            # This 
                puts "+++++++++++++++++\n"
            set ipaddr "0.0.0.0"
            set limit 4
            set splitip [split $ipaddr "."]
                puts "Split ip address = $splitip"

            # MAIN ROUTINE
                    set ilength [llength $splitip]
                    puts "Length of string is $ilength"

                    set first [lindex $splitip 0]
                    set  sec [lindex $splitip 1]
                    set third [lindex $splitip 2]
                    set four [lindex $splitip 3]
                        for { set limit 1} { $limit >0} {} {

                            for { set first $first } { $first <= $limit} {} {

                                    for { set sec $sec } { $sec <= $limit} {} {

                                            for { set third $third } { $third <= $limit} {} {

                                                for { set four $four } { $four <= $limit} {} {
                                                    puts " f:$first $sec $third $four"
                                                    incr four
                                                }
                                        set four 0
                                        incr third;                                                     #puts " t:$four $third $sec $first\n"


                                            }
                                        set third 0
                                    incr sec

                                    }
                                                                #puts " f:$four $third $sec $first"
                                        set sec 0
                                incr first

                            }
                        incr limit -1
                        }

            # End Main


                puts "\n++++++End Program+++++++++++"
```

Comment: If you really handle IP adresses, maybe have a look at the tcllib ip package too. ( http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/tcllib_ip.html )

Comment: Thanks schlenk for that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program essentially boils down to this, does this do what you intended?

```
for { set first 0 } { $first <= 1} {incr first} {
    for { set sec 0 } { $sec <= 1} {incr sec} {
        for { set third 0 } { $third <= 1} {incr third} {
            for { set four 0 } { $four <= 1} {incr four} {
                puts " f:$first $sec $third $four"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because if so, the primary suggestion is to simply remove everything except this.

Also: `[llength $splitip]` does not give you the *string* length of `$splitip`, but the *list* length. Those are different.

You're using a very roundabout way to assign values to `first` et al.  Instead, use

```
lassign $splitip first sec third four
```

The `lassign` was added in Tcl 8.5. If you're using an older version of Tcl, use assignment by `foreach` instead:

```
foreach {first sec third four} $splitip break
```

The construct

```
for { set limit 1} { $limit >0} {incr limit -1} { ... }
```

simply means "execute ... exactly once": it doesn't affect the program's execution in any way. Even if you remove it (keeping the code inside the *body* argument), the code that was inside it will still execute exactly once.

For clarity, the `incr x` invocations should be inside the third argument to `for`, not inside the fourth, *body*, argument.

As a final note, if your intent is to print out a sequence of binary numbers, it's a lot easier to do that this way:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 16} {incr i} { puts [format %04b $i] }
```

Comment: Yes ! I guess so. Just needs the reset to 0 after each loop(??) but you are right.

Comment: Wow ! thanks for your suggestions !! it will make my programming a lot better.

Comment: sorry , new user. din't know about this option.

Comment: thanks for the tip to print bin no's but the intention was to use the loop so that i get better at it :)

Comment: I suspected that, but it felt wrong not to mention the other way.